# Execute loadrunner Script

Tags: linux, testing, loadrunner

I would like to know how I can run Loadrunner Scripts from Linux console. The scripts are ".usr". I tried to launch them from cmd and everything ok but what I need is from linux console.

Answer (score 0):

Running scripts directly from the console Linux or Windows is not officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't. Linux is currently used only as a Load Generator, and not an initiator of a Load test.
Hope this helps,
Lior